# Store pointer in array of pointers and return it from function

Tags: c++, arduino

Could someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Actually I want `getPointer()` to return an array (with size of 3 pointers) of pointers to integers. That's my main plan. An alternative for me was to return a pointer to that array of pointers.

```
int value = 5;
int *(*array1)[3];


int* (*getPointer())[3] {
  int *pValue= &value; 
  array1[0] = pValue; // throws the error
  return array1;
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

That's the error message:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int* [3]'

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? what are you trying to solve with array of 3 `int*` ?

Comment: @alve89 This  int *(*array1)[3]; is not a declaration of an array. It is a declaration of a null-pointer to an array of three pointers.

Comment: Long story short: Due to an unexplainable linking error (undefined reference to....) I'm trying to "re-learn" the basics because I'm an absolute newbie. That's a very basic example for using pointers and arrays. The actual array is not of type `int*` but of type pointer to user defined type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What am I supposed to do then to correctly declare an array of pointers? And could you please explain me "a declaration of a null-pointer to an array of three pointers"?

Comment: @alve89 this should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: @alve89 `int *foo[42]`. But you can't return a plain old array of anything by value in C++.

Comment: @alve89 Just write int * array1[3];

Comment: `std::array` can be returned, though.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sure, that's quite obvious, my mistake... But how can I return a pointer to that array by function? So what was the correct function declaration?

Comment: The array would just be used as an output parameter, typically.

Comment: @alve89 If you want to return the array then the return type of the function should be int **. That is an array designator used in expressions including using them in the return statement is converted to pointer to its first element.

Comment: @alve89 Another approach is declare the return type as a referenced type to the array type.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself by adding an `&` to the return and changed the array declaration to `int *array1[3]`:

```
int value = 5;
int *array1[3];


int *(*getPointer())[3] {
  //int *pValue= &value; 
  array1[0] = &value;
  return &array1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an argument you don't use in the function? Do you intent to use it in some code that isn't shown?  Also, generally it's not a good idea for functions to change globals without a compelling reason.

Comment: @doug: The problem is that I got a very weird linking error (undefined reference) while trying to directly access a global array. As a workaround I thought of a "handler function".

Comment: Your function returns a ptr to an array of ptrs to ints.Your global is an array of ptrs to ints. So the return statement now returns a ptr (from the `&`) to an array of ptrs to ints.. That is it's just a ptr to the global. That's why `&array1` works and `array1` doesn't in the return statement. BTW, I misread the code originally. It doesn't have any arguments.